# VBscript to search file

Tags: vbscript

At the moment, I have a large text file which batch file can not handle to search the lines. The code below can search the value "9200.... 9300 " if the number of lines in that text file is not long.
Even the problem is also that this code returns the value in the same line with 9200.... I only want to crop the value 9200 range to 9300

But whenever, I used it for the large text file (500MB), it is gives strange character. I think I need VBScript to find only this number and I will display that in a message.

The code is

```
for /f "usebackq delims=* tokens=5" %i in (`findstr "9201.. 9200.." data.mud`) do @echo %I
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you give an example of input and desired output? Also, what are the "strange character" you get? Is the input file perhaps Unicode encoded or binary?

Comment: Thank you Ansgar for your response. It is Unicode latin character. If you see that Data.mud is not a text file, but can be opened in Notepad. Trying to write a script that will search for the range of 9200 to 9200. And if the                                           for /f "usebackq delims=* tokens=5" %i in (`findstr "9201.. 9200.." data.mud`) do @echo

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. Is the file a Unicode (text) file? Or is it not a text file (i.e. a binary file)? And what do you mean by "range of 9201 to 9200"? Do you want the script to output everything between the two strings "9201" and "9200"? If so, does 9201 always come before 9200?

Comment: Sorry Ansgar, it is a text file. It is range between 9201 to 920150. The script should find a range of number between these numbers and output it. Thanks

Comment: So, for two numbers 9201 and 9500 you'd want the output to be any number from `data.mud` that is between 9201 and 9500?

Comment: So you want all text contents between 9201 and 920150 or lines with 9201, 9202, ... , 920150? Does this data.mud have line breaks? If not, it will be a different approach.

Comment: Thanks! It has line breaks. The data.mud is associated with a card reader, so because the card is used with different device, it generates a differenet serial number between 9201, 9202.....920150. I am trying to create a script that will let us know which device generates between this serial number. It will definitely be one of these numbers.

Comment: Could you please answer the question whether you want just the numbers or the whole lines containing those numbers?

Comment: I just want the number to be found. and I can then use it to display a message. Thank you Ansgar.

Comment: Thank you so much Ansgar Wechers.I will just now change it for message box. It is very imporatnt. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "\d+"
re.Global  = True

filename = "C:\path\to\data.mud"
lb = 9200
ub = 920150

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  For Each m In re.Execute(f.ReadLine)
    n = CLng(m.Value)
    If n >= lb And n <= ub Then WScript.StdOut.WriteLine n
  Next
Loop
f.Close
```

You need to run this script with `cscript.exe`:

```
cscript //NoLogo C:\path\to\your.vbs
```

Comment: It gives error The handle is valid Line 12 Char 33 code : 80070006 source(null).                                                  which is this line : If n >= lb And n <= ub Then WScript.StdOut.WriteLine n

Comment: @moshaye3 - use cscript.exe instead of wscript.exe.

Comment: Thank you very much Ekkehard. It works using cscript.

Comment: Yeah, I actually meant `cscript`. Fixed.